# deny all outgoing calls and access with AMI

Tags: php, asterisk

here is my scenario:
I want to make an AMI with PHP, when user click to call on web, it makes an outgoing call with originate login and...
so, I just have to deny all outgoing calls and allow it when user click on web, it get allow permission, call number and then hangup, after that get deny permission again.
I don't want to get your source code, I just want to know my scenario is true and applicable or not and what is the method when I deny all calls and then allow during calling on click on web.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any scenario can be got on asterisk.

You have create two context. One for your phones without external access(optional local calls phone2phone) other one is for your dialout application. 
Also in dialout context you can check some variable set by script.
For more info check any book,i recomend "Asterisk the future of telephony".

Answer (score 0):

You can have the asterisk dialplan decide whether to put the call out or not, but this shouldn't be a decision made by asterisk, but rather by your php script that initiates (originates) the call. Have the login decision logic in your php script, not in asterisk.